# In what order does CMake evaluate OR and AND in compound 'if' condition?

Tags: cmake, operator-precedence

The CMake documentation states:

> The following syntax applies to the condition argument of the if,
> elseif and while() clauses.
>
> Compound conditions are evaluated in the following order of
> precedence: Innermost parentheses are evaluated first. Next come unary
> tests such as EXISTS, COMMAND, and DEFINED. Then binary tests such as
> EQUAL, LESS, LESS_EQUAL, GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL, STREQUAL, STRLESS,
> STRLESS_EQUAL, STRGREATER, STRGREATER_EQUAL, VERSION_EQUAL,
> VERSION_LESS, VERSION_LESS_EQUAL, VERSION_GREATER,
> VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL, and MATCHES. **Then the boolean operators in the
> order NOT, AND, and finally OR**.

But the following prints 'FALSE':

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(Test)

if(YES OR NO AND NO)
    message("TRUE")
else()
    message("FALSE")
endif()
```

I'd expect the expression to evaluate as `YES OR (NO AND NO)`. What's going on?

Comment: Here is a link to the CMake issue tracker: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23207).

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the maintainers' response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not a bug in the implementation, but in the documentation. CMake is (mis)designed to evaluate `AND` and `OR` at the same precedence, and from left to right.

See the MR that will update the documentation here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/6970